# Rails: Passing multiple parameters to form_for url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This works great:

```
- form_for @user, :url => { :action => :create, :type => @type } do |f| ...
```

Returns `/users/(id)?type=type`

But in another view I need to pass TWO parameters into the URL string, and this does not work:

```
- form_for @user, :url => { :action => :update, :type => @type, :this => @currently_editing } do |f| ...
```

Returns `/users/(id)?this=currently_editing`

I've also tried:

```
- form_for @user, :url => { :action => :update, :params = params.merge({:this => @currently_editing, :type = @type})} do |f| ...
```

... with no luck (error: only GET requests allowed).

What I want is for it to return this: `/users/(id)?this=currently_editing&type=type`

Thoughts?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Why do you need to pass them into the URL string?  Why not just add them as hidden fields in the form?  In almost all cases you should pass the variables that way with POSTs.

Comment: would hidden fields work for parameters that are not part of the post model?

Comment: You can still add the hidden fields to the form, you don't have to use the form_for helpers for it.

Answer (score 2):

I would use hidden fields, but this should work:

```
<% form_for @user, :url => user_path(@user.id, :type => @type, :this => @currently_editing), :method => :put do |f| -%>
```

`:method => :put` triggers the update action when using RESTful routes.

Answer (score 2):

please try to this

you can pass more than one parameter in this way.

```
- form_for @user, :url => xxx_yyy_path(:param1 => value1, :params2 => value2, ......) do |f| ...
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you have to move the desired querystring attributes outside of the :url option like this:

```
form_for @user, :url => { :action => :update }, :type => @type, :this => @currently_editing do |f|
```